# How to get the value of an HTML control whose ID changes dynamically? (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and stuck at one point. Need your help.

I have 2 dropdowns, not the normal 'Select' ones, but made with the help of Unordered list and CSS. Something like:

Dropdown 1:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" min-width: 180px;">
@foreach(Fruit item in Fruits)
 {
 <li><a id="@("FR_" + @item.FruitID)" onClick="RefreshPullDown(this.id)">@item.FruitName</a></li>
 }
</ul>
```

Dropdown 2:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" min-width: 180px;">
    @foreach(Vedgetable item in Vegetables)
     {
     <li><a id="@("VEG_" + @item.VegetableId)" onClick="RefreshPullDown(this.id)">@item.VegetableName</a></li>
     }
    </ul>
```

As you can see, in both the dropdowns, the IDs are generated dynamically. Now my aim is to populate a table based on the selected values of both Dropdown 1 and Dropdown 2. If the user changes any of the values of any of the 2 dropdowns, my table should be populated with the new values taking the new values in DD1 and DD2. Following Javascript function I tried (when Dropdown 1 value is changed):

Javascript:

```
    function RefreshPullDownValue(anchorId) {
var fruitAnchorId;
    var vegAnchorId;
    if (anchorId.indexOf('FR') >= 0) {
        fruitAnchorId = anchorId;
    }
    else {
        VegAnchorId = anchorId;
    }
        var fruitValue = &('#' + fruitAnchorId).text();
//How to fetch the other dropdown value here??
    // code to call controller and get the table populated..
        }
```

Problem here is I can get the value of the list item which is clicked. How am I suppose to get the value which is already selected in the other DD at the same time, since its ID is dynamic and not fixed.I need to get both the dropdown values in one JS function in order to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you add a new parameter to the function RefreshPullDownValue(), which will give you an indication of which pulldown is being affected. In this way, you can store (globally?) which item is being selected for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can store values on click something like this.

```
<li><a id="@("VEG_" + @item.VegetableId)" onClick="StorePullDownValue(this.id, 'first')">...</li>
```

Second dropdown

```
 <li><a id="@("VEG_" + @item.VegetableId)" onClick="StorePullDownValue(this.id, 'second')">...</li>
```

In your js

```
var dd1 = null,
    dd2 = null;

var StorePullDownValue = function(value,type){
  if(type == "first"){
      dd1 = value;
   }else{
      dd2 = value;
   }
  if(dd1 != null && dd2 != null){
     // call your function here to generate a table
  }
 }
```

You can also use jquery to simplify your code and make it better.

Comment: this code will get the value of either of the dropdowns and not both. i.e. if any list item of DD1 is clicked, the variable dd1 will get populated with the id and dd2 will remain as null. I want the ID of the other selected List item (of second dropdown) at the same time. And vice versa.

Comment: U 'll select values from both dropdown. When u 'll do it then it 'll generate. Coz when u refresh page I guess no value will be selected and then user 'll select a value from first dd and then second.

Answer (score 0):

in the first DD the IDs concatenated with "FR__"

```
id="@("FR_" + @item.VegetableId)"
```

in the second DD the IDs concatenated with "VEG_"

```
id="@("VEG_" + @item.FruitID)"
```

So you already knows when you did that :

```
    if (anchorId.indexOf('FR') >= 0) {
        fruitAnchorId = anchorId;
   //first DD
    }
    else {
        VegAnchorId = anchorId;

   //second DD
    }
```

Comment: @@Ahmed You should ask your question in comments instead of answering it.

Comment: @GeekyNinja i have modified my answer thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this simply by changing your code in jquery like this @Nehal

HTML

```
    // Dropdown 1
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 180px;"> 
    @foreach(Fruit item in Fruits)
     {
     <li><a id="@("FR_" + @item.FruitID)" class="fruitItem">@item.FruitName</a></li> 
     }
    </ul>
   // Dropdown 2
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 180px;">

         @foreach(Vedgetable item in Vegetables)
         {
         <li><a id="@("VEG_" + @item.VegetableId)" class="vegItem">@item.VegetableName</a></li>
         }
        </ul>
```

Jquery

```
$('a.vegItem').on('click', function (event)
{
      var VegSelection= $(this).text();
   alert(VegSelection);
});

 $('a.fruitItem').on('click', function (event)
{

   var FruitSelection= $(this).text();
   alert(FruitSelection);
});
```

checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raghucse2010/c4jjzhvw/8/) for understanding. Hope this helps you.